# sqlite3 crashes in iOS 9.0 device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite, ios9

I had developed an application which uses the SQLite database. It was working perfectly fine until iOS 8.4 on both iOS simulators and devices but on iOS 9.0 it is crashing by giving error "database is locked" on physical device while working perfectly on iOS 9.0 simulator.

It is giving error in SQLiteManager.m

Please note that:

1. I am using XCode 7.0 Beta 3
2. My physical device has iOS 9.0 Beta 3 which is the same version of my iOS simulator
3. I have set the build target to 9.0 which was initially showing many warnings but I have updated all the deprecated things in the code according to iOS 9.0 like UIAlertControllerView etc.
4. There is no warning in code now.
5. I have tried by deleting and adding again both libsqlite3.0 and libsqlite framework. But the error is still there.
6. I have read many blogs and even on Stack Overflow  related to this and found solution of writing sqlite3_close(database) and sqlite3_finalize(command) after execution of command and I have done that too, but still failed to achieve any output.

Comment: I have the same problem since iOS9.. did you find any solution on this?

Comment: same issue for me too

Comment: Its automatically resolved in iOS 9.0 Original release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was problem in compatibility. It has been resolved automatically since X Code 7 and iOS 9  Beta 5 is released.